# Two equivalent generic types are treated differently in function body

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type that accepts type `T` as generic argument.

In a generic function's type arguments I derive `T` from an object's keys using `Pick`.

If I use an intermediate type variable to get these keys, it fails to act as T in the function body. If I skip the intermediate variable (everything else is the same) it acts like T!

[Well annotated example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCuBcEsBsAJwPa0gOwM4AcCmBjc8BPbNAKHCK1gEkATAHgBUA+WAXlgdiwA9wsUaaWAgBGAK1z4A-LADeAX1gAyObADaABWQpYAaywEEAMw4BdAFzV6DTaZaLLDANwkQAWg8eSZCrACC0NAA0gZC7ABEAOYICDT6BACM4bAAPrBRMXEGAEzJaeEiAIZZBOEu5NiwAOKZIQRh6dGx8UmpjZnxuU6wIChIRSXeIJH8WABOkDiElQgo0ASwhTg4WBjgQk00eqE+lVWjEzgMFIxcvPyC1bWhLOyyJLCwaAgAtljgABaokY4k8i6uYCFHSiCR4aaUADukE+-gAMnDtvVYAAKTaLASwAYASl2lD8KAA8uJJAB1GEfALBUJsVRqeLafyBOpoCwYhb-bw8DAIMb4IygFB4SCzWAjFDjSYAMUFwtmdAeTOp9WJYjOfAEQgJqrJFKpLIANIqQMDhCTwdDYbN5mLMki0OZFRpxi8YXwaKr1RchBpJro6PrQqqDVdYiymEbHiA0B8EKBoFtrQsRJR0fEhCIIFwxmNeUJCvmIYsxpFQG8UPhULABUKoKKRLECIqqCgjOMxlgaM6xq7wO6WQBRHO8r2apHGWDd3vu4PG4A8JbgG1oQpvRb5hsAN0oSbOGGBNE7qLEoDQ+D62j4Pc7kEKfAhuMeLbbOc7U7dnZZADlCUPc2NR0ueIJ19HB-UDFVxBDGowxuI0mBREhsTkOdIQ+BZICET5MOECUxUgTdvgxbN-yecAJhQSI2hQMsUwAtI0AIF4G2gAByZAhD6fACzQSBIhQQoRGgShECLViYJoFlWMVCpKD-Wl9glQ5jmwOhn3bN8XQ-STQj-XkmBcKNgEzfBPkoLAAEdQAIwphIrXDKBoBAsE4hBwCkKQZN8L8EHk9hFMlI4TnU18uy0vtP1CH89LGAzvCMjtwFAMYdFkrCkFQTBJEVRLkp0GjAnXWBBV0PpIR0At1BCjswp7bTB2HMYQ2qzS6oinT6mixrTBceRvFk2AACV3lpYakpSlSsDoWSJ3FQKZVrEUUDiwFY23ACEHWiF80xMyFkKDt4A+SgVzeABCPFYD-SbaVoOgxrUAAGOxym83ycxu9g7oehIXqAA) (this is the shortest I could make it)

Reproduced below:

```
//util to inspect types
type Id<T> = T extends object ? {} & { [P in keyof T]: Id<T[P]> } : T;
//-----

type AllKeys = "goodkey1" | "goodkey2" | "badkey";
type GoodKeys = "goodkey1" | "goodkey2"; //no badkey

//generic type only accepts good keys
type GenericType<T extends GoodKeys> = {
  something: T
};

//an object type with ALL keys (good and bad)
type AnObjectWithAllKeys = { [key in AllKeys]: any };

export function genericFunction<
  AllKeysObj extends AnObjectWithAllKeys,
  //an object with only good keys:
  PermittedObj extends Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>,
  //should only be good keys but errors as a type argument in function body
  InferredPermittedKeysError extends keyof PermittedObj,
  //exactly same as above only expanded (just no intermediate type)
  InferredPermittedKeysNOError extends keyof Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>,
>(
) {
  //why is this one giving an error string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'GoodKeys'
  type Err = GenericType<InferredPermittedKeysError>;
  //but the equivalent one does not??
  type NoErr = GenericType<InferredPermittedKeysNOError>;

  //return types to inspect
  return null as unknown as [InferredPermittedKeysError, InferredPermittedKeysNOError];
}

type Ret = ReturnType<typeof genericFunction>;

//hover over types and they are the same!
type ErrType = Id<Ret[0]>;
type NoErrType = Id<Ret[1]>;
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `InferredPermittedKeysError` is defined as a subtype of `keyof PermittedObj`, and `PermittedObj` is *any subtype* of `Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>`, which means it can have arbitrary properties in addition to `GoodKeys`. So `InferredPermittedKeysError` could be an arbitrary property name, it does not have to be a subtype of `GoodKeys`.

For example:

- Suppose `AllKeysObj` is just equal to `AnObjectWithAllKeys`.
- Suppose also that `PermittedObj` is the type `{goodkey1: string, goodkey2: string, foobar: string}`, which is indeed a subtype of `Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>`.
- Then `keyof PermittedObj` would be the union type `'goodkey1' | 'goodkey2' | 'foobar'`.
- Then suppose `InferredPermittedKeysError` is the type `'foobar'`, which is allowed because it is a subtype of that union type.
- Of course, `'foobar'` does not extend `GoodKeys`.

In contrast, `InferredPermittedKeysNOError` must indeed be a subtype of `GoodKeys`, because it is defined as a subtype of `keyof Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>` which is equal to the type `GoodKeys`. So in fact your two generic types are *not* equivalent; your `Id` function is giving the wrong result here.

To confirm, the following call is allowed, with no type errors:

```
// const test: ['foobar', 'goodkey1']
const test = genericFunction<
  AnObjectWithAllKeys,
  {goodkey1: string, goodkey2: string, foobar: string},
  'foobar',
  'goodkey1'
>();
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCuBcEsBsAJwPa0gOwM4AcCmBjc8BPbNAKHCK1gEkATAHgBUA+WAXlgdiwA9wsUaaWAgBGAK1z4A-LADeAX1gAyObADaABWQpYAaywEEAMw4BdAFzV6DTaZaLLDANwkQAWg8eSZCrACC0NAA0gZC7ABEAOYICDT6BACM4bAAPrBRMXEGAEzJaeEiAIZZBOEu5NiwAOKZIQRh6dGx8UmpjZnxuU6wIChIRSXeIJH8WABOkDiElQgo0ASwhTg4WBjgQk00eqE+lVWjEzgMFIxcvPyC1bWhLOyyJLCwaAgAtljgABaokY4k8i6uYCFHSiCR4aaUADukE+-gAMnDtvVYAAKTaLASwAYASl2lD8KAA8uJJAB1GEfALBUJsVRqeLafyBOpoCwYhb-bw8DAIMb4IygFB4SCzWAjFDjSYAMUFwtmdAeTOp9WJYjOfAEQgJqrJFKpLIANIqQMDhCTwdDYbN5mLMki0OZFRpxi8YXwaKr1RchBpJro6PrQqqDVdYiymEbHiA0B8EKBoFtrQsRJR0fEhCIIFwxmNeUJCvmIYsxpFQG8UPhULABUKoKKRLECIqqCgjOMxlgaM6xq7wO6WQBRHO8r2apHGWDd3vu4PG4A8JbgG1oQpvRb5hsAN0oSbOGGBNE7qLEoDQ+D62j4Pc7kEKfAhuMeLbbOc7U7dnZZADlCUPc2NR0ueIJ19HB-UDFVxBDGowxuI0mBREhsTkOdIQ+BZICET5MOECUxUgTdvgxbN-yecAJhQSI2hQMsUwAtI0AIF4G2gAByZAhD6fACzQSBIhQQoRGgShECLViYJoFlWMVCpKD-Wl9glQ5jmwOhn3bN8XQ-STQj-XkmBcKNgEzfBPkoLAAEdQAIwphIrXDKBoBAsE4hBwCkKQZN8L8EHk9hFMlI4TnU18uy0vtP1CH89LGAzvCMjtwFAMYdFkrCkFQTBJEVRLkp0GjAnXWBBV0PpIR0At1BCjswp7bTB2HMYQ2qzS6oinT6mixrTBceQhmAWAcFmM94Bc8BLDUVijBiIoxlYkNWM2FpWNMEghvQUyxtpcVAplWsRRQBVHm1c1wHJT4ILQSM5CWgwEksM8KMiENboIbIHvI74Q2m0RCjGD6nvka6ppmv75sVRaOju6SEOxFwgA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, I understand the difference now.

Comment: Do you think there is a viable way to have "generic type constants" that hold a "is" relationship and not "extends"? Above, I don't actually want `PermittedObj` to /extend/ `Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>` but /be/ that, and only that - the motivation is I need that value in other generic parameters. Now the only solution I know is to copy paste `keyof Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>` everywhere which looks gnarly and will be hard to maintain. In the real world, all these params are inferred and not user provided so I can't take them outside the generic params either.

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to just repeat `Pick<AllKeysObj, GoodKeys>`. The only alternative I can think of is to have a `GoodKeysObj extends AnObjectWithGoodKeys` type parameter instead of `AllKeysObj`, and then if you need `AllKeysObj` then you could define it with reference to `GoodKeysObj` rather than the other way round. I'm not sure exactly how that would look; it probably depends on your use-case.

Comment: Thank you again. What I resorted to is the following: Since I have one required type argument and all others are derived from that one required one, I need to use "function with required type parameters returning function with optional type parameters" trick (since optional generic parameters are all or nothing in TS for now, you have to provide none, or all, or have defaults for optionals). I can set intermediary types with `type X = ...` between my outside function (that has the required type param) and the inside function (with inferred type params) without any `extends`.